# Creating a private cluster in GKE, terraform vs console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been trying to setup a terraform module to create private cluster, and I'm struggling with a strange situation.

When creating a cluster with a master authorized network, if I do it through the GCP console, I can create the private cluster just fine. But when I do it with Terraform, I get a strange error:

```
 Invalid master authorized networks: network "<cidr>" is not a reserved network, which is required for private endpoints.
```

The interesting parts of the code are as follows:

```
....
master_authorized_networks_config {
  cidr_blocks {
    cidr_block = "<my-network-cidr>"
  }
}

private_cluster_config {
  enable_private_endpoint = true
  enable_private_nodes    = true
  master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "<cidr>"
}
....
```

Is there something I'm forgetting here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Google Cloud Platform documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters), it should be possible to have both private and public endpoints, and the `master_authorized_networks_config` argument should have networks which can reach either of those endpoints.

If setting the `enable_private_endpoint` argument to `false` means that the private endpoint is created, but it also creates the public endpoint, then that is a horribly mis-named argument; `enable_private_endpoint` is actually flipping the public endpoint off and on, not the private one.  Apparently, specifying a `private_cluster_config` is sufficient to enable the private endpoint, and the flag toggles the public endpoint, if reported behavior is to be believed.

That is certainly the experience that I had: specifying my local IP address in the `master_authorized_networks_config` caused cluster creation to fail when `enable_private_endpoint` is `true`.  When I set it to `false`, I get both endpoints and the config. is not rejected.

Comment: > that is a horribly mis-named variable.
I absolutely agree with you on this. In GCP console, the relevant flipper is called "Access master using its external IP". No mention of none of that in this terraform variable `enable_private_endpoint`

Comment: For further clarification: https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/blob/master/docs/private_clusters.md#troubleshooting.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue recently.

The solution I found is to set the `enable_private_endpoint = false`.

In this case the private endpoint created anyway, but you are allowed to add CIDR with external addresses to master authorized networks.

Answer (score 4):

```
master_authorized_networks_config {
}

private_cluster_config {
  enable_private_endpoint = true
  enable_private_nodes    = true
  master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "<cidr>"
}
```

Should create the private_end_point and it won't complain about `Invalid master authorized networks`. The one you tried, is passing up the external CIDR for the whitelist to access the public endpoint while at the same time you want it to be strictly private.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. I created cluster from console and then try to create it with terraform but no ide about this issue..

Comment: Thanks, this should be the right answer. To prevent anyone from actually specifying a CIDR within the `master_authorized_networks_config` block.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by myself, I guess I should have read the all the documentation on the gcp side in detail.

The problem here is that I'm adding a master authorized network cidr range to enable local network access, that is an external address and from the GCP documentation

> You cannot include external IP addresses in the list of master authorized networks, because access to the public endpoint is disabled.

If you are curious, and want know more click [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters)

Comment: But why it works when creating a cluster in GCP console? I have the same issue here.

Comment: The difference I think is with the option to enable private endpoint. I don't think that is an option directly exposed in the console.